“It’s fast holding by the rings in front” in Browning’s ‘Fra Lippo Lippi’
In ‘Fra Lippo Lippi’ (1855) by Robert Browning, the speaker, the painter Filippo Lippi, says:

I’m grown a man no doubt, I’ve broken bounds:
You should not take a fellow eight years old
And make him swear to never kiss the girls.
I’m my own master, paint now as I please—
Having a friend, you see, in the Corner-house!
Lord, it’s fast holding by the rings in front—
Those great rings serve more purposes than just
To plant a flag in, or tie up a horse!

What does the speaker mean by “it’s fast holding by the rings in front”?

To the downvoter: Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking? The answer is yes.

The “Corner-house” was mentioned earlier in the poem:

                                                Who am I?
Why, one, sir, who is lodging with a friend
Three streets off—he ’s a certain … how d’ ye call?
Master—a … Cosimo of the Medici,
I’ the house that caps the corner

This identifies the location as the palace of Cosimo de’ Medici, now the Palazzo Medici Riccardi, on the corner of the Via de’ Gori and the Via Camillo Cavour in Florence. The palace has rings stapled to the stone-work in front, as in this image from Google Street View:


Iron rings are attached to the sides of the windows for the purpose of holding banners or for illuminations, whilst those below were for torches. The larger rings were used to tie the horses of visitors to the palace.
Susan and Joanna Horner (1873). Walks in Florence, volume 2, page 147. London: Strahan.

The historical Lippi painted many works for Cosimo, and according to Vasari (Browning’s source for the poem), he was so prone to riotous living that his patron tried at one point to confine him to the palace so that he could spend more time painting:

It is said that he [Lippi] was so amorous, that, if he saw any women who pleased him, and if they were to be won, he would give all his possessions to win them; and if he could in no way do this, he would paint their portraits and cool the flame of his love by reasoning with himself. So much a slave was he to this appetite, that when he was in this humour he gave little or no attention to the works that he had undertaken; wherefore on one occasion Cosimo de’ Medici, having commissioned him to paint a picture, shut him up in his own house, in order that he might not go out and waste his time; but after staying there for two whole days, being driven forth by his amorous—nay, beastly—passion, one night he cut some ropes out of his bed-sheets with a pair of scissors and let himself down from a window, and then abandoned himself for many days to his pleasures.
GIorgio Vasari (1550) Lives of the Most Eminent Painters Sculptors and Architects, volume 3. Translated by Gaston Du C. De Vere (1912). Project Gutenberg.

So by “fast” Lippi means “in a secure position”—clinging to the train of a rich patron like Cosimo is a more secure position than trying to earn a living on one’s own, just as holding onto the metal rings of the palace is more secure than standing on one’s own feet, especially if one is as drunk on “Chianti wine” as Lippi seems to be in the poem.

Fra Lippo, at the time of his monologue, paints neither in the monastery, which is dedicated to pure idea and total abstraction, nor in the street, which is too close to the chaos of raw reality. Instead, he chooses the house of Cosimo of the Medici, certainly very much of the world and yet secluded from it. From hence, Lippo is relatively free to come and go. The gusto of the street is just outside the window if needed for inspiration and energy. Such was very obviously the case when Lippo, “three weeks shut within [his] mew, … could not paint all night” and so “leaned out of window for fresh air.” Yet the house is available as a retreat—if the watch will allow Lippo to return to it. There he finds the artistic freedom from monastery control which he needs for full creative expression. “I’m my own master, paint now as I please.” But if he has escaped the crippling, externally imposed restrictions of the monks, he imposes a liberating control upon himself by voluntarily returning to the house whose name offers security and whose thick walls insure order and detachment. This must surely be the significance of Lippo's reference to “fast holding by the rings in front” of the Medici palace.
Glen Omans (1969). ‘Browning’s “Fra Lippo Lippi,” a Transcendentalist Monk’. Victorian Poetry 7:2, page 137.


"he was so prone to riotous living". I think it's worth mentioning that he was a Carmelite friar (hence "Fra") who quit the monastery but was never released from his vows. He even got a nun or novice pregnant...
